# Learning Perl having the shell script knowledge-need help

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have shell scripting knowledge.
I have written a small shell script which will take a single argument.
with the help of that argument.

the file name format is `axeA10_<date_time_stamp>_<sequence_number>.DAT`
my script just takes all the files in the current directory and changes the sequence number.
so that i have the files with sequence numbers.
the need to write this script is that i dont have the files with the sequence number as some of the sequences are missing.

I know that `perl` can be more fast in doing this kind of tasks.And so i want to learn the same.
Can anyone convert this small shell script to `perl`.this would really boost my confidence in learning `perl`.Thanks in advance.Below is the script which works fine.

```
#!/bin/ksh

counter=1
for i in ${1}*.DAT
do
if [ $counter -lt 10 ]
then
new_name=`echo "$i"|awk -vcount=$counter 'BEGIN{FS="_";OFS="_"}{$3=count}{print $1"_"$2"_0"$3".DAT"}'`
else
new_name=`echo "$i"|awk -vcount=$counter 'BEGIN{FS="_";OFS="_"}{$3=count}{print $0".DAT"}'`
fi
mv $i $new_name
counter=$(($counter+1))
done

exit
```

Comment: Please have a go at writing the Perl script yourself and ask *specific* questions when you get stuck.

Comment: [Tutorials on perldoc.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Can anyone convert this small shell script to perl.this would really boost my confidence in learning perl."

How would someone doing this **for** you boost your confidence?
Visit the following URL

http://learn.perl.org/